# Understanding the Ruby mixin's proxy class mechanism

Tags: ruby, module, scope, mixins, proxy-classes

I am refering to the follwing article, paragaph "Pitfall #1": http://definingterms.com/2013/03/23/pitfalls-of-ruby-mixins/

I've got the following setup, a slightly changed form of the one used in the article:

```
module EmailReporter
    def send_report
        #Sending a report ...
        puts self.class
    end
end

class Person
end

class Employee < Person
    include EmailReporter
end
```

As I understand, when I include EmailReporter in Employee, its methods are not just pasted into it, but a anonymous proxy class is created and put into the inheritance chain above Employee and under Person.

When I call Employee.new.send_report, I am not in the scope of Employee, but in the scope of the proxy class. Thus, I would not have access to constants or class variables of Employee, but I would have access to instance variables.

**Questions:**

1. If I run Employee.new.send_report, the output is "Employee", but not something like "Employee__proxy_class". Why is that? Shouldn't "self" refer to the proxy class?
2. The article suggest the proxy class delegates method calls to the Module EmailReport. But of course you cannot just call instance methods on it. So whom does the proxy class delegate its calls to?

Thanks to everyone trying to answer my question!

Comment: self refers to the receiver that is why many of the methods in ruby work. Take a method like `#send` for example. `#send` is defined in `Object` but you wouldn't want `Employee.send` to be executed in the context of `Object` itself and lose the context of `Employee`. included modules while they may be an `include class` in essence inject their methods into the class in which they were included. The reason this is done at a higher level is to allow you to overwrite methods in the class itself. All methods are delegated up the chain of inheritance unless `method_missing` interrupts this.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Regarding self, of course you are right and I don't know why I didn't get that.

So does that mean the graphic in the article (http://definingterms.com/images/posts/mixins_d3.jpg) as well as the word proxy class is misleading because the proxy class above Employee does not delegate to any other class but holds the methods itself?

Comment: I would say that it is a bit misleading. I think the reason he refereed to this as a proxy is because it can be included anywhere, does not conform to the single inheritance principal and breaks encapsulation.

Comment: another interesting thing to note is 2 include statements on top of each other act as the author describes where the second takes precedence over the first but `include Module1, Module2, Module3` will be evaluated in the reverse order including `Module 3` then `Module2` and finally `Module1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your fundamental problem is in understanding the value of `self`. Often it's helpful to just add code that tells you what `self` is at different points of your code. Let's begin with a very simple example:

```
class Dad
  def hi
    puts "self in Dad#hi = #{self}"
  end
end

class Son < Dad
end

son = Son.new
  #=> #<Son:0x007fc1f2966b88>
son.methods.include?(:hi)
  #=> true
son.hi
  # self in Dad#hi = #<Son:0x007fc1f2966b88>
```

Just because:

```
son.method(:hi).owner
  #=> Dad
```

does not mean `self` is changed when `hi` is invoked on `self`. Now let's include a mixin:

```
module Helper
  def hi
    puts "self in Helper#hi = #{self}"
  end
end

Son.include Helper

son.hi
  # self in Helper#hi = #<Son:0x007fc1f29551d0>
son.method(:hi).owner
  #=> Helper
```

I think you understand why `Helper#hi` was invoked here rather than `Dad#hi`.

Does this answer your first question? I don't understand the second question, but perhaps you can answer it yourself now that you've been enlightened on `self`. If not, please clarify #2 (with an edit to your question).

Comment: Thank you! This reinforces engineersmnky's answer in my post's comment. #2 was about me being confused that the author wrote about a "proxy class" - I thought of the proxy pattern and combined with the graphic (definingterms.com/images/posts/mixins_d3.jpg), I thought the proxy class would delegate to another class, which it does not.